# Fire an event when records exist based on some query

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a table, that people insert records on it (status=0), and other team updates the table (with the frontend) setting status=1.

I want to have something that can give me an event to perform some task, when records with status=0 are inserted, in that very moment (ok with seconds delay) without using timers and check it every X seconds.

The query would be something like:

```
select count(*) as ok from tbl where status=0;
```

How could this be made/which technology/functions?

Comment: Perhaps a mysql trigger? It depends on what needs to happen in this event and if it can be handled through mysql alone. I've never done it, but you could use the `system` command in mysql (potentially in a trigger???) to reach out to the shell, perhaps to touch a file for a watchdog.

Comment: why can't you use timer?

Comment: You could use a client server set up. When the client inserts the record it can trigger an event on the server.

Comment: Devart provide commercial tools for MySQL and they include a `MySqlDependency` class that mimics the `SqlDependency` class provided by Microsoft for SQL Server. I don't know how the Microsoft class works but the Devart class for MySQL actually uses a `Timer` internally, so there may not be a way that you can do it yourself with using a `Timer` at some level.

Comment: Well, if I use the mysql trigger i won't have that in the .net side.
Well i'm actually using a timer right now every 30 seconds, I just tought there was something more native that could trigger this for me

Comment: if you willing to use microsoft sql server or PostgreSQL there are solution like [Query Notifications in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/query-notifications-in-sql-server), otherwise i think there is no notification service in mysql, but you can mix trigger with lock and unlock and run a query on your application in a thread, when trigger unlock certain data then your application will be able to read that data so you kind of simulate notification service.